# How would I draw a line using canvas if i touch the image using onTouchevent?

Tags: android, android-canvas, touch-event

How would I draw a line using  canvas if i touch the image using onTouchevent .here i am using imageview as a background and position it based on x/Y co-ords? Also, is it possible to check if a line is drawn at those co-ords? Actually if i draw a line ,it would be overlapped the image view.the line should draw image itself inside the layer.how to calculate image x,y position
    Thanks,

Comment: explain in detail ? Cant get what you want

Comment: draw a line using onTouchevent in the image background withpout overlapped

Comment: what do mean by "without overlapped" ??

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int eventaction = event.getAction(); 


   int X = (int)(event.getX()); 
   int Y = (int)(event.getY()); 

   switch (eventaction ) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        canvas.drawLine(X,Y,someOtherX, someOtherY, paint):
            break;
      <snip>
   }
```

If you want to check if a line is already drawn at coordinates X,Y, then you have to keep
a list or Array of the lines you've already drawn with their start/stop coords or slope/intercept and do the algebra.  You've got your current line from X,Y to SomeOtherX,Y.
It would be a simple process of going through each line and finding where, if at all, the two lines intersect and if they intersect on screen.

Comment: is it possible to include the  canvas.drawLine inside the ontouchevent function

Answer (score 0):

is merely a shorthad ywa of saying there is more code here, but not important to the point you asked.

How to solve for intersection of two lines, say, these two, in slope-intercept form

y = 3x-3
y = 2.3x+4

At the point of intersection they will both have the same y-coordinate value, so we set the equations equal to each other:
3x-3 = 2.3x+4

This gives us an equation in one unknown (x) which we can solve:
Re-arrange to get x terms on left   3x - 2.3x = 4+3
Combining like terms    0.7x = 7
Giving  x = 10

To find y, simply set x equal to 10 in the equation of either line and solve for y:
Equation for a line y = 3x - 3  (Either line will do)
Set x equal to 10   y = 30 - 3
Giving  y = 27

We now have both x and y, so the intersection point is (10, 27)